# Is there a way to update my terminal on the mac?

Tags: macos, module, terminal, quandl

I am using a MacBook pro and my terminal version in 2.7.2. However, I have downloaded both python2 and python3. When I 'pip install quandl' in the terminal I can import it using python2 but not python3?! Is this because my terminal is not updated or because the module is not supported my python3?

Comment: If you want to use it in Python 3, run `pip3 install quandl`, or use virtualenvs to manage interpreters and dependencies.

Comment: This very likely has nothing to do with your terminal emulator. Your `pip` is likely pointing to Python2 `pip`, try using `pip3`, which should be pointing to your Python 3 interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a different pip command to install modules for python3. The command is `pip3` so to install the quandl module for python 3, run `pip3 install quandl`.

Comment: Thanks man! It is quite frustrating as a beginner when you get so many errors trying to download modules. But this works fine!